# Connectivity to Sybase from Databricks

Tags: azure, sybase, azure-databricks, sap-iq

What is the best way to connect to Sybase from Databricks?

```
>     %sql
>     
>     CREATE TABLE sybase_table
>     USING org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc
>     OPTIONS (
>       dbtable 'table_name',
>       driver 'sybase.jdbc.driver.SybaseDriver',
>       user 'username',
>       password 'pasword',
>       url 'jdbc:sybase:thin://@<hostname>:1521/<db>')
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, connectivity to Sybase is not supported as a source in Azure Databricks.

These are the supported Data sources in Azure Databricks:

•   SQL databases using JDBC

•   SQL databases using the Apache Spark connector

•   Azure Blob storage

•   Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2

•   Azure Data Lake Storage

•   Azure Data Lake Storage credential passthrough

•   Cosmos DB

•   Azure SQL Data Warehouse

•   Binary file

•   Cassandra

•   Couchbase

•   ElasticSearch

•   Image

•   Hive tables

•   MLflow experiment

•   MongoDb

•   Neo4j

•   Avro files

•   CSV files

•   JSON files

•   LZO compressed files

•   Parquet files

•   Redis

•   Riak Time Series

•   Snowflake

•   ZIP files

As per my research, I have found a third-party tool named "Panoply" which can [integrate Databricks and Sybase using Panoply](https://panoply.io/integrations/databricks/sybase/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: There should be a way to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

> 1- Install the "**jconnect4**" library on the Databricks cluster
>   http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.1/dbprogramming/jconnect-using-jdbxextra.html

2- Run the following code in the Databricks notebook:

> ```
> %sql
> CREATE TABLE <YOUR_TEMPORARY_TABLE_NAME>
> USING org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc
> OPTIONS (
> dbtable 'OAIRestricted.OAIR_MasterCoordinate',
> driver 'com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver',
> user 'YOUR_USERNAME',
> password 'YOUR_PASSWORD',
> url 'jdbc:sybase:Tds:HOSTNAME_IP:5000/DATABASE_NAME')
> ```